# How to remove slider part in timeline.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline.js

I was trying to remove the slider part in timeline.js . What I tried was just adding display : none in html file.

```
<div class="vco-slider" style="overflow-y: hidden;display : none">
```

This html line was generated automatically. I want to know in which file should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your main CSS Stylesheet. Under that, apply a class with `display:none;` value.

You can find the files under the folder called "Source" with the CSS file that you are currently using.

**For Instance,**

```
.vco-slider{
   display:none;
}
```

Hope this helps.